# How do I program a bluetooth module to broadcast a text string to an iOS device?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to figure out how to send a simple text string from a BlueGiga BLE112 bluetooth module to an iOS device using BGScript. Is this possible? If so, what steps do I need to take to get this to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a custom GATT service with a characteristic containing your string. Then the iOS device could connect and read it. There is also the standard Device Information service which contains various string characteristics such as manufacturer name, serial no., device id etc. Maybe you could use that if it is suitable for your application. Your BGSript code among other things could set the value of the characteristic at run time if it is not constant. You can create the service using Bluegiga's Profile Development Kit. Documentation can be found here [BLE112 Documentation and Software](https://www.bluegiga.com/en-US/products/bluetooth-4.0-modules/ble112-bluetooth--smart-module/documentation/).